# MoveFirst DoEvents MoveLast

Tags: sql

This is probably the simplest fix, but I need to get the Autonumber and store it to a public variable that will be used to identify the session the user is in. This ID is used when the User logs off to close a session. The **Bolded** code was used strictly in ACCESS, but I have now moved the tables over to SQL and now this code does not work. Hence,the code below needs to be modified to fit with the rest of this code. I need the Recordsource to be the dbo.tTbl_LoginSessions. The LngLoginID is used later. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this. What I have learned is that a Stored Procedure will not work, @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, and IDENT_CURRENT are similar functions but I have heard that these can be suspect. This email makes me appear smarter than I appear, but trust me I am not. Therefore, I need baby steps.

```
    Function CreateSession()
'This closes the open session
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String
Dim WhoAmI As Long

Dim StrLoginName As String, StrComputerName As String

'passing variables
StrMSID = StrLoginName
StrComputerName = FindComputerName

'Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
strSQL = "Insert into dbo.tTbl_LoginSessions(fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fldComputerName) Values ('" & StrMSID & "','" & Now() & "','" & StrComputerName & "')"

'connect to SQL Server
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con
.ConnectionString = cSQLConn
.Open
End With
'write back
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With CMD
.ActiveConnection = con
.CommandText = strSQL
.CommandType = adCmdText
.Execute
End With

'/Next get the autonumber and store it to a public variable that will be used to
'/identify this session.

'/This id is used when user logs off to close this session.
**Rs.MoveFirst**    
**DoEvents**
**Rs.MoveLast**
**LngLoginId = Rs(0)** 
Debug.Print strSQL
'close connections
con.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing



End Function
```

THIS WAS THE OLD CODE, BEFORE I CONVERTED IT. Everything but the Autonumber works

```
 Function CreateSession(WhoAmi As Long)
    '/This function records the details regarding the login details of the person

    Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset


Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_LoginSessions")
    Rs.AddNew
    Rs.Fields("fldUserName").Value = StrLoginName
    Rs.Fields("fldComputerName").Value = StrComputerName
    Rs.Fields("fldLoginEvent").Value = Now()
    Rs.Update
    '/Next get the autonumber and store it to a public variable that will be used to
    '/identify this session.
    '/This id is used when user logs off to close this session.
    Rs.MoveFirst
    DoEvents
    Rs.MoveLast
    LngLoginId = Rs(0)

    Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Makes me shudder looking at vb6...but anyway, scope identity will work fine assuming you are grabbing it directly after the operation

Comment: What would be the line that I would need to replace the Rs.MoveFirst, DOEvents, Rs.MoveLast, LngLoginId = Rs(0) , because everything I put in there seems to error out and does not seem to work for me? What if someone logs in right at the same time, which could happen.

Comment: I.m on my mobile at the moment but ill be back home shortly, ill help you out when I get back!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the immediate output ->Insert into dbo.tTbl_LoginSessions(fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fldComputerName) Values ('','10/31/2013 3:32:45 PM','LH7U0CNU139430Z') The first quotes should have an integer, to identify the user.

Comment: The problem here is that you are calling a SQL command (an insert operation) to insert data into SQL - which without any follow up doesn't return anything. The fundamental difference here is that you are using the `OpenRecordset` command in access in the original code. This creates a cursor object which lets you walk through the records in the table one by one (forward or backwards etc). You can't do this with SQL - you need to execute a SQL batch (one or more SQL statements) and the batch can return values or datasets. `MoveNext`/`MoveFirst` etc won't work because you haven't opened a cursor

Comment: I'd consider using a sproc - I'm not sure why you say they won't work - a sproc will work absolutely fine. I'll post an example as an answer - bear in mind it's been about 3 billion years since I've touched VB6. Is this project too big to rewrite in a newer technology such as VB.NET or c# (I prefer c# by far as I find the syntax is more terse)

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want something like so: (bear in mind I haven't got VB installed  to check this so it might not be 100%)

```
' Create command
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command

Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1 ' Whatever your open conn object is - you've got a conn already by the looks of things

' Point the command at a sproc
Cmd1.CommandText = "sp_YourSprocName"
Cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

' Add parameters
Cm1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter ("fldLoginName", adVarChar, adParamInput, fldLoginName) 
Cm1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter ("fldLoginEvent", adVarChar, adParamInput, fldLoginEvent) 
Cm1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter ("fldComputerName", adVarChar, adParamInput, fldComputerName) 
Cm1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter ("ReturnValue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue) 

' Run the command
Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()

Cmd1.Parameters("ReturnValue").Value ' Contains the return value of the sproc
```

I'm not sure how easy it is to do this as you are already doing it using transactions instead of a sproc as making the whole process atomic with a transaction would work (then you could issue the INSERT and the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call in one go)

... though to be honest depending on the project size I'd consider re-implementing in newer tech if you are looking at further development. VB is getting a bit long in the tooth (Obviously, there's nothing wrong with VB6 if you have apps written in it that are working fine and you don't need to re-write)

Same data access code in Entity Framework would be a couple of lines of really expressive code e.g.

```
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var newSession = new LoginSession();

    newSession.UserName = "Fred";
    newSession.LoginEvent = "?";
    newSession.ComputerName = "Some Computer Name";

    ctx.LoginSessions.Add(newSession);

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // newSession.SessionId would contain the new ID
}
```